# asp.net mvc log4postsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postsharp, log4postsharp

Hi Iam trying to use log4post sharp for logging purposes, As far as Iam aware I have followed the instructions to get this up and running, I  have not installed postsharp, rather I got the library files and midified my cs proj file to target those file, I have also tried installing postsharp on my machine. In either case I end up with this error

Error   5   The plug-in "Log4PostSharp" required by the type "Log4PostSharp.LogAttribute" was not found.

I have tried googling this and it seems there is no trace of this issue anywhere on the web.

One difference between my implementation with other examples is that the postsharp dll that they use is PostSharp.public, mine is just PostSharp. I have tried searching for the former dll but cannot find it anywhere, the download only contains PostSharp.dll. I feel this may be the issue as I have followd all the insturctions to the letter to get this up and running. Any Ideas People?

Answer (score 2):

The plug-in should be installed in the PostSharp search path as documented at http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/1.5/Content.aspx/PostSharp.chm/UserGuide/Platform/Advanced/SearchPath.html.

Answer (score 0):

I havnt used log4post but a nice suggestion for logging web applications.
"ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment"

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/